# grub-mkrescue not creating ISO file

Tags: grub2, 17.04

I am following the instructions from the [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Making-a-GRUB-bootable-CD_002dROM) to create a GRUB rescue CD using the `grub-mkrescue` command as mentioned in the manual.

This is the command I used `grub-mkrescue -o grub.iso` to create the rescue CD, however, it does not create any ISO file when the command finishes and no errors were outputted to the terminal. So I tried the same command again but this time with the `--verbose` flag: `grub-mkrescue -o grub.iso --verbose` and I get the following output (trimmed down to where multiple copies failed, please go here for the full output https://paste.ubuntu.com/24934730/ because I can't post all of it here because of the character limit):

```
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu32.o' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu32.o'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu32.o': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu64.o' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu64.o'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/efiemu64.o': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/moddep.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/moddep.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/partmap.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/partmap.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/parttool.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/video.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/video.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh'.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/gez/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/gez.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/gez/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/an.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/an/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ml.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fa_AF/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fa_AF.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fa_AF/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sr@Latn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sr@Latn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sr@Latn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/my/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/my.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/my/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/mg.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/hi.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ne.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/zu.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/lb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/lb.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/lb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/kw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/kw.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/kw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fr.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/be@latin/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/be@latin.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/be@latin/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/si.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ko.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/dv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/dv.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/dv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/haw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/haw.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/haw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ca@valencia/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ca@valencia.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ca@valencia/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/jv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/jv.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/jv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/uk.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/en_GB.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/th.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fi.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/gv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/gv.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/gv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ta.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sml/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sml.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sml/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/shn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/shn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/shn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sw.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sw/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/bn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/kk.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/kk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ti/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ti.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ti/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/gl.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sr.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ja.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/vec/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/vec.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/vec/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/en@quot.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sr@latin.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/kn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/is.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/locale.alias.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/locale.alias/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': Not a directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/xh.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/wo/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/wo.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/wo/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/gu.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/vi.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/et.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/zh_TW.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/zh_HK.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/frp/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/frp.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/frp/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/en.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/he.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ar.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/zh_CN.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/af.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/nds/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/nds.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/nds/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ms.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/os/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/os.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/os/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/as/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/as.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/as/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/te.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fur/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fur.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fur/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ace/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ace.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ace/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ast.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/en@boldquot.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/bg.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/mk.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/dz/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/dz.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/dz/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/bo/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/bo.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/bo/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sd/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sd.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sd/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ka.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/so/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/so.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/so/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/pam/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/pam.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/pam/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ary/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ary.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ary/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/km.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sv.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fy/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fy.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fy/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/csb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/csb.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/csb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/or.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/fil/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/fil.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/fil/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ps/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ps.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ps/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/pt_BR.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/nb.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sl.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/bs.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sco/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sco.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sco/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ve/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ve.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ve/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/chr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/chr.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/chr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/az.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/byn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/byn.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/byn/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/se/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/se.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/se/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/wae/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/wae.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/wae/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/mr.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/sq.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/oc.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ln/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ln.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ln/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/tg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/tg.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/tg/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/mt.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/mt/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/eu.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/tt/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/tt.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/tt/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/tk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/tk.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/tk/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/szl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/szl.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/szl/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ky/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ky.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ky/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/ckb.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/ckb/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/hr.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/uz.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/uz/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/mi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/mi.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/mi/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
grub-mkrescue: info: copying `/usr/share/locale/bem/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo' -> `/tmp/grub.jzt2g1/boot/grub/locale/bem.mo'.
grub-mkrescue: info: cannot open `/usr/share/locale/bem/LC_MESSAGES/grub.mo': No such file or directory.
```

As you can see from above output, it failed to copy multiple files because they don't exist. How can I fix this issue? I am running `Ubuntu 17.04 / 64 bit`.

Comment: First use ubuntu pastebin for such large issues. Second I am not sure where the command puts the .iso so see if you can find it `sudo updatedb && locate grub.iso`. If you can not find the .iso I suggest you install the missing files and/or file a bug report against grub.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I couldn't find anything with the command you provided. How would I install the missing files? I've been googling for this for almost 2 hours now.

Comment: Most of those are in the package grub-pc-inb, so you have that package installed?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/grub-pc-bin/filelist . or use the search function - https://packages.ubuntu.com/ see the "Search the contents of packages

This search engine allows you to search the contents of Ubuntu distributions for any files (or just parts of file names) that are part of packages. You can also get a full list of files in a given package." so, for example, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=grub.mo&searchon=contents

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yep that's it, installing the `grub-pc-bin` package worked for me. The `grub-mkrescue` command now completed successfully and the `grub.iso` file was created. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments, the solution was to install `grub-pc-bin`

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin
```

The way to identtify the missing package was to search for the files on https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Under the "Search the contents of packages" section using file names.

> Search the contents of packages
>
> This search engine allows you to search the contents of Ubuntu
>   distributions for any files (or just parts of file names) that are
>   part of packages. You can also get a full list of files in a given
>   package.

Alternately you can install and use `apt-file` to search the repos for files, but it takes longer typically then a web search.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

Search in which packages for file(s)

```
apt-file search file_name
```

In this case, from the error message,

```
apt-file search efiemu32.o
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem running :

```
grub-mkrescue -v -o ~/grub.iso
```

using apt-file (thank's to Panther) :

```
francis@tito2:~$ apt-file search efiemu64.o
grub-coreboot-bin: /usr/lib/grub/i386-coreboot/efiemu64.o
grub-ieee1275-bin: /usr/lib/grub/i386-ieee1275/efiemu64.o
grub-pc-bin: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/efiemu64.o
```

Why prefer **grub-pc-bin** package rather than **grub-coreboot-bin** one ?

I got also another problem :

```
Your xorriso doesn't support `--grub2-boot-info'...
Please use xorriso 1.2.9 or later.
```

So I had to install **xorriso** package to override GRUB's builtin, and it works.

Finaly, it seems that the absence of *certain files* does not prevent the making of the iso file.